# IIF query using OR operators not working

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2003

I'm trying to run the following as criteria in an MS access query. Basically what I want to do is:

- If checkbox = True then all records, including those with blank or Null fields are shown (the default value in my form's combo box [combo9] is "*")
- If checkbox = False then only records that match the value in Combo9 are shown

My current expression doesn't give any errors, but also doesn't produce any results! The TRUE and FALSE halves of the expression work fine on their own, but don't work when combined into the iif expression.

```
Like IIf([Forms]![F_leg_reg]![Check25]=True,Like [Forms]![F_leg_reg]![Combo9] Or "" Or Is Null,Like [Forms]![F_leg_reg]![Combo9])
```

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10):

Not sure you need so many `likes`, you are using the `or` logical operator in the return value which doesn't make sense

```
IIF (condition, value-if-true, value-if-false)
```

so..

```
Like IIF ([forms]![foo].[text1] = "1" OR [forms]![foo].[text2] = "1", 'bar', 'foobar')
```

if either conditions are met IIF will return 'bar' else it will return 'foobar'

you can nest it if you want so

```
Like IIF ([forms]![foo].[text1] = "1" OR [forms]![foo].[text2] = "1", 'bar', 
        IIF ([forms]![foo].[text1] = "2" AND [forms]![foo].[text2] = "2", 'foobar', null)
    )
```

if either conditions are met IIF will return 'bar' else we check to see if `text1` **and** `text2` are "2" if so return 'foobar' else we return `null`

hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You're repeating the keyword, Like, within the IIf() expression.  That won't work.  You could fix the IIf(), but I would use a different approach ... which fits my brain better.

This will returns all rows when the checkbox is checked, but no rows when unchecked.

```
SELECT a_field, another_field, field_2_search 
FROM YourTable
WHERE [Forms]![F_leg_reg]![Check25]=True;
```

When the checkbox is unchecked, limit the rows to those where the field_2_search values contain the combo's value.

```
SELECT a_field, another_field, field_2_search
FROM YourTable
WHERE
    [Forms]![F_leg_reg]![Check25]=False
    AND field_2_search Like "*" & [Forms]![F_leg_reg]![Combo9] & "*";
```

But you want only one query, not two, so combine those WHERE clauses with an OR.

```
SELECT a_field, another_field, field_2_search 
FROM YourTable
WHERE
    [Forms]![F_leg_reg]![Check25]=True
    OR (
    [Forms]![F_leg_reg]![Check25]=False
    AND field_2_search Like "*" & [Forms]![F_leg_reg]![Combo9] & "*"
    );
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm struggling to see where field_2_search comes into this though. I've tried replicating this code in my query as best as possible by creating a new text box names field_2_search but with no luck

Comment: OK sorry, I now see that field_2_search is the field in my table that I'm trying to search

Comment: Hmm.  Would have been clearer with field_2_search included in the SELECT list.  I'll do that now; sorry it's too late to help you.

Answer (score 1):

I am very late coming to this discussion, but I found this post when I encountered the same problem.  I have since solved it, and want to share.

The problem is the location of your Iif statement.  Since you are using Access, you are probably placing the Iif statement in the Criteria row on the query design view.  Delete that.  Instead, you need to make the Iif statement its own field in query.

You also need to be very careful with the oporators you use with Null and "*".  The syntax is very touchy.

In a new query field, enter:

```
IIf([Combo_Box] Is Null,[Field1] Is Null Or [Field1] Like "*",[Field1]=[Combo_Box])
```

Then set the criteria for that field to be <> False.

The SQL would look like this:

```
SELECT [Field1], [Field2], etc
FROM Table1
WHERE (IIf([Combo_Box] Is Null,[Field1] Is Null Or [Field1] Like "*",[Field1]=[Combo_Box])<>False);
```

Hope this helps!  Sorry for being so late to the party!.