# Syntax Error issues around Case When

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to write the following query for Microsoft Access and am encountering issues around the last three characters here, Can someone tell me what's wrong with my syntax for Access purposes:

SELECT DISTINCT Searches.Search ,IIF(Chemical_Names.Category  IS NOT NULL, Chemical_Names.Category, IIF(CAS_Numbers.Category IS NOT NULL , CAS_Numbers.Category, IIF(Brand_Name.Category IS NOT NULL, Brand_Name.Category,
IIF(PART.Category IS NOT NULL , PART.Category,CAT.Category))))  AS Category
FROM Searches 
     LEFT JOIN
       (SELECT * FROM Cat1 UNION
        SELECT * FROM Cat2 UNION
        SELECT * FROM Cat3 UNION
        SELECT * FROM Cat4) as CAT
    ON
                       Searches.Search = CAT.Search
     LEFT JOIN
       (SELECT * FROM Part1 UNION
        SELECT * FROM Part2 UNION
        SELECT * FROM Part3 UNION
        SELECT * FROM Part4) as PART
    ON
                       Searches.Search = PART.Search 
      LEFT JOIN
       Supplier_Name
    ON
                       Searches.Search = Supplier_Name.Search 
      LEFT JOIN
       Chemical_Names
    ON
                       Searches.Search = Chemical_Names.Search
     LEFT JOIN
       Chemical_Names
    ON
                       Searches.Search = CAS_Number.Search
     LEFT JOIN
       Brand_Name
    ON
                       Searches.Search = Brand_Name.Search;

Comment: Which RDBMS is this? SQL Server?

Comment: @GregoryHigley It is MS Access, as the tag and text state.

Comment: I corrected the tag to `ms-access`. `access` is as clear as mud.

Comment: There is no CASE WHEN in your code, and SWITCH isn't available in any version of Access SQL I've ever seen. Are you looking for IIF() (or IFF() - it's been a long time since I wrote any Access SQL) instead?

Comment: Try using `IIF(situation, do-this-when-true, do-this-when-false)` instead of `switch`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9310098/iif-query-using-or-operators-not-working for an example

Comment: Switch is most definitely a function available in MS Access SQL. The CASE WHEN function is not, though.

Comment: I've never done a nested switch statement in SQL and I can't find any documentation that says you can or can't do it in principle. You can try using the IIF instead and see if that works.

Comment: @Kenwhite Access does indeed have the Switch function.

Comment: I tried updating with IIF still gives me a syntax error not sure why, though I can't tell which part it thinks is wrong, it highlights a couple of letters "Sear"?: SELECT DISTINCT 
               Searches.Search 
               ,IIF (Chemical_Names.Category  IS NOT NULL, Chemical_Names.Category,
                      IIF (CAS_Numbers.Category  IS NOT NULL , CAS_Numbers.Category,
                      IIF (Brand_Name.Category     IS NOT NULL,  Brand_Name.Category,
       IIF (PART.Category IS NOT NULL ,  PART.Category,   CAT.Category))))  AS Category
   FROM Searches

Answer (score 2):

I think you can try using the `Nz()` function to conditionally show the first non null category in your chain of preference:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    Nz(Chemical_Names.Category,
        Nz(CAS_Number.Category,
            Nz(Brand_Name.Category,
                Nz(PART.Category, CAT.Category)))) AS Category
FROM Searches
...
```

The `Nz()` function is Access' version of what would be `COALESCE()` in most other databases.

You could also handle this use `IIF()`, which is Access' version of the `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    IIF(Chemical_Names.Category IS NOT NULL, Chemical_Names.Category,
        IIF(CAS_Number.Category IS NOT NULL, CAS_Number.Category,
            IIF(Brand_Name.Category IS NOT NULL, Brand_Name.Category,
                IIF(PART.Category IS NOT NULL, PART.Category, CAT.Category)))) AS Category
FROM Searches
...
```

Comment: what would be the equivalent of a Case When? I want to try to keep as much of what I have unless its necessary to change it to get it to work in access.

Comment: @mkheifetz You could also use the `IIF` function which is Access' version of the `CASE` expression you know from most other flavors of SQL.

Comment: yep, I tried doing that just like with the switch above, it gives me a syntax error just like the one above except with IIF syntax for some reason

Comment: are there any other errors in other parts of my query because that change still keeps telling me I have a syntax error...

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your desired result, Switch should be applied as follows:
`Switch(Chemical_Names.Category IS NOT NULL, Chemical_Names.Category, CAS_Namber.Category IS NOT NULL, CAS_Number.Category, Brand_Name.Category IS NOT NULL, Brand_Name.Category, PART.Category IS NOT NULL,  PART.Category, 1=1, CAT.Category) AS Category`

Comment: I just tried doing this and it still gives the same message that there is a syntax error... not sure what to do

Comment: Does the query run if you remove that entire calculated field? If not, then it's probably something in your joins. The easiest thing might be to rebuild it using the query designer. If it does run without the calculated field, then rebuild the switch statement one pair at a time.

Comment: what do you mean by the calculated field? how do you rebuild and what does that do?

Comment: Calculated field = the formula = the entire 'switch' statement. Rebuild = reconstruct/reassemble = start over piece by piece (table by table). First make sure the joins work, without the switch, iif or whatever you choose to use. Then you can put the formula together piece by piece.